# "at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" error on heroku, how to fix?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, heroku

Deployed on heroku with Intellij Spring boot using gradle. However, when I try to connect with the distributed url, the following error message appears.

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=[my_url] request_id=[...id] fwd="xxx.xx.xxx.xxx" dyno= correct= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

As a result of running `heroku logs --dyno router` in the directory where the source file is located, only an error was output. How can I solve this?

### [EDIT]

The error message is:

[image]

Comment: You need to provide the entire log. From the moment you start the application until the moment you visit your website. That single log line you provided just says your application is not running. The question is why your application is not running. There are log messages as well when the application stops running.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for the late reply. I have attached a picture of the error message.

Comment: The error is a problem in your application, not Heroku: `no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/heroku_connection-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar`

Comment: I googled and came up with some advice to try: ```jar { manifest { attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.myapp.HeroConnectionApplication' } }``` in ```build.gradle``` . But I'm getting a ```ClassNotFoundException``` and it's still not working. How should I add the manifest?

Comment: @H.JiMan hello there, have you solved this problem or not? Thank you for any information